# Alternative particle types?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, particle-physics, mass, charge

If we consider mass and charge to be excitations of independent quantum fields, do they necessarily travel together? Can we have objects with only an excitation on the mass field, and objects with only an excitation on the charge field? Could the latter be light?

Comment: I don't know about mass-charge separation, but you can have spin-charge separation  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spin%E2%80%93charge_separation

Answer (score 4):

There are no mass and electric charge fields. Instead, there is an electron field, a photon field, a quark field, a gluon field, etc. Mass and electric charge are properties of field quanta. Electrons and quarks both have mass and electric charge; photons and gluons have neither.

You can definitely have mass without electric charge. For example, a Z boson does, and neutrinos too (since they are believed to have a small mass).

There are no known particles with electric charge but without mass.

Comment: I posit they are light.

Comment: Justification : Symmetry

Comment: Light <=> em in general

Comment: There have been plenty of experiments on photons, from very low-energy ones to very high-energy ones. There has never been *any* evidence that they have even the slightest bit of electric charge. You seem to have a fundamental misunderstanding of electromagnetism. Electric charge causes an electromagnetic field, but that does not mean that an electromagnetic field has charge. This has been understood for 150 years.

Comment: BTW, gluons are massless particles that *do* have a kind of charge, but it isn’t electric charge; it’s “color charge”. The fact that photons don’t have the kind of charge for the force they carry, while gluons do, can be understood theoretically in terms of the different *symmetry groups* for their interactions. A commutatve symmetry group, like electromagnetism’s U(1), means no charge on the force-carrying particles. A noncommutative symmetry group, like SU(3) for the color interaction, means charge on the force-carrying particles. So symmetry *is* involved, but *not* like you think.

Comment: Saying “I posit” in a physics forum is a bad idea until you have actually studied and understood physics. And, even then, this site has no interest in any personal theories. We deal only with mainstream physics here.

Comment: So what is carrying the charge that creates the em wave that you call light?

Comment: @NonSecwitter  the comment above is another question, though equally confused. Look at the classical modeling of light https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electromagnetic_radiation , there is no charge and it is self propelled. In the quantum level light is a superposition of photons which are elementary point  particles of zero mass and charge.  for field theory try https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/physics/8-323-relativistic-quantum-field-theory-i-spring-2008/

Comment: @NonSecwitter Light from the sun consists of electromagnetic waves emitted by charged nuclei and electrons in the Sun, 93 million miles away. Light from a light bulb consists of electromagnetic waves emitted by electrons in the atoms in the bulb. In general, light *comes* from charge, but *has* no charge.

Comment: @NonSecwitter I encourage you to keep asking questions, to keep learning physics, and to keep wondering how the world works. But I encourage you to accept that real theory-making is something you do *after* you become an expert in a field and understand deeply what is good and what is bad about the currently accepted theories.